# Overtraining with imbalanced data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to perform a binary classification on some imbalanced data (~20:1 ratio) and have gotten almost perfect cross-validation accuracy but terrible prediction rates with data not used in the training/testing. There are several thousand negative examples and a few hundred positive examples. This data has been normalized and SMOTE was used to balance the class distribution.

Using RandomForests classifier the KFold cross-validation is almost perfect but the recall/accuracy values are between 0.1-0.3. I have tried different balancing methods, PCA (there are about 80 original features), multiple classifiers, CV Grid optimization, and even combining trees after 8-fold training but none of these significantly improve the results.

I was a little surprised how well the training went compared to the fresh data. Is it possible this is because of over-training? I was hoping the combining of the trees would help alleviate this but it has not been the case.
This data might be difficult to classify with the available features but is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Yes its absolutely possible. Or maybe the fresh data is very different from the train/ cross-validation data used. By the way, as this question is less about programming and more about the approach or technique, this is unsuitable for stackoverflow.com. Try this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com along with some more details about the code, the data and the precise steps you took.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually quite simple. With classifications this imbalanced you need to *weight* your classifications so your model learns how to classify true and false equally, without having to discard a huge chunk of your data!

Try something like this quick example:

```
def calculate_class_weights(train_classifications):

    one_count = 0
    zero_count = 0
    one_weight = 0

    for i in train_classifications:
        if i == 1:
            one_count += 1.0
        if i == 0:
            zero_count += 1.0

    if one_count > zero_count:
        one_weight = one_count / zero_count

    if one_count < zero_count:
        one_weight = zero_count / one_count

    return one_weight
```

This will give the the relative 'weight' of the positive classification compared to the negative classification. You can then call your model like this:

```
classifier = svm.SVC(probability=True, class_weight={1: one_weight})
classifier.fit(training_set, train_classifiers)
```

So here the weighting of the negative is 1, and the weighting of positive is whatever was previously calculated. Could be 0.5 if there are twice as many positives as there are negatives, for example.

Good luck!